# Error updating Dockerfile FROM php:7.2-fpm to php:7.3-fpm

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, updates, php-7.3

Because I want PHP 7.3 features I am trying to update the project from PHP 7.2 to PHP 7.3. Within docker-compose.yml I have:

```
php:
    build: ./docker/php
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
    links:
        - mysql:mysql
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    networks:
      - pimcorenet
```

My Dockerfile is like:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

# install git
RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git

#install some base extensions
RUN apt-get install -y \
        zlib1g-dev \
        zip \
        libpng-dev \
        exiftool \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libicu-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libxpm-dev \
        libvpx-dev \
        mariadb-client \
        libxml2-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        zip \
        exif \
        bcmath \
        intl \
        pcntl \
        mysqli \
        pdo \
        gd \
        pdo_mysql \
        pdo_pgsql \
        mbstring \
        soap \
        opcache \
        iconv

# Install Imagick
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

# Install Composer
RUN echo "Install Composer"
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN composer --version
```

I am getting the following error:

> E: Failed to fetch
>   http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/readline/readline-common_7.0-5_all.deb
>   Could not resolve 'cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org' E: Failed to fetch
>   http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/j/jquery/libjs-jquery_3.3.1~dfsg-3_all.deb
>   Could not resolve 'cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org' E: Failed to fetch
>   http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/freetype/freetype2-doc_2.9.1-3_all.deb
>   Could not resolve 'cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org' E: Failed to fetch
>   http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/icu/icu-devtools_63.1-6_amd64.deb
>   Could not resolve 'cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org' E: Failed to fetch
>   http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/j/javascript-common/javascript-common_11_all.deb
>   Could not resolve 'cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org' ..... more errors
>
> ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get
>   install -y         zlib1g-dev         zip         libpng-dev
>   exiftool         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev
>   libmcrypt-dev         libicu-dev         libpq-dev         libxpm-dev 
>   libvpx-dev         mariadb-client         libxml2-dev' returned a
>   non-zero code: 100

What is the exact problem with this? Is it because some required PHP extensions are not yet available for PHP 7.3 or have been replaced? How do I resolve this? Just changed `FROM php:7.2-fpm` to `FROM php:7.3-fpm`.

Comment: try with 7.3.9-fpm-stretch

Comment: @LinPy ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries

Comment: the errors you get is from the underlying OS since they come from apt-get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are failing to [grok](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/grok.html) containers. And because of that you are taking the wrong approach.

You shouldn't be trying to 'upgrade' a php 7.2 to container to 7.3.

You should be creating a new container image that is based off 7.3 to begin with.

Incidentally, I would recommend making it me a new, separate service to your existing 7.2 container, i.e. a new Dockerfile, rather than just changing the existing container/Dockerfile. That will allow you to test the two versions alongside each other, rather than having a 'leap of faith' change over.

Also, I'd recommend building off the Debian or Ubuntu images directly, rather than going through the 'official' Docker images. They are only official in the sense of being made by Docker, but they are not quite as well supported in my opinion.

This is the dockerfile I'm using currently: https://github.com/Danack/example/blob/master/docker/php_fpm/Dockerfile Switching 7.2 to 7.3 should 'just work'.

Comment: Some useful tipps definitly. Sorry if this is a noob question I am still pretty new to docker.

Comment: Started of with a PHP 7.3 image and adjusted the libs to my needs from my previous image. All works, thanks!

Comment: Oops, forgot to link to the docker file that builds from debian.

Comment: Imagick is an installable extension in Debian, so you don't need a lot of those steps.